# HTML要素の終了タグの仕様を確認したい

Tags: html, html5, xhtml

`<div>`タグは終了タグが必要

```
<div>あいうえお</div>   これはＯＫ
<div>あいうえお         これはＮＧ
```

`<br>`タグは終了タグを書いてはいけない

```
<br>        これはＯＫ
<br></br>   これはＮＧ
```

`<li>`タグは終了タグを省略できる

```
<ul>
  <li>あいうえお</li>   これはＯＫ
  <li>あいうえお        これもＯＫ
</ul>
```

どのタグが終了タグ必須で、どのタグが終了タグ不可、という仕様を確認できる資料を探しています。
HTML4やHTML5、XHTMLなどで微妙に仕様が異なる点もあると思いますが、HTML5だけの仕様でも構いません。
一覧のような形でまとめて確認できるものがあれば教えてください。

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HTML5に関してですが、[W3Cの勧告](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/)を見ると[Elementsの章](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#elements-0)に以下のように書かれています。

- 通常要素で終了タグを省略できるとなっていない物は省略できない（The start and end tags of certain normal elements can be omitted, as described below in the section on optional tags. Those that cannot be omitted must not be omitted.）。省略できる物の一覧は[コチラ](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#syntax-tag-omission)。
- [空要素](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#void-elements)は終了タグを付けてはダメ（Void elements only have a start tag; end tags must
  not be specified.）。

Answer (score 3):

HTML4以前限定ですが、[DOCTYPE宣言で指定されているdtd](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html)の`<!ELEMENT HOGE` に続く2つの値が開始、終了タグの省略可否を表し、`-`であれば省略不可、`O`(OmittableのO)であれば省略可能となります。

> <!ELEMENT BR - O EMPTY                 -- forced line break -->
>
> <!ELEMENT DIV - - (%flow;)*            -- generic language/style container -->

Answer (score 2):

先に回答が出ていますが、詳しい解説および自分の復習もかねて、まとめを。
概ね、省略しても文章構造が理解できる(つまり、普通は入れ子にしないだろう・普通はこの次にこれを入れるだろうというような組み合わせ)のものが終了タグの省略が可能だったりします。
・・とはいえ、おおよそのものが「スタートタグ・エンドタグ双方の省略が不可」です。

以下タグについては、その下記条件を満たすことで省略が可能です。

**開始タグ省略可能**

- HTML
  *最初の文がコメントでない場合*
- HEAD
  *空要素の場合　または　最初の文が他の要素である場合*
- BODY
  *空要素の場合　または　直後が空白文字またはコメント　または　meta, link, script, style templateの各ではない場合。*
- COLGROUP
  *最初の要素がcol要素かつ、直前に終了タグが省略された別のcolgroupが存在せずかつ、空要素でない場合*
- TBODY
  *最初の要素がtrでかつ、終了タグが省略された別のtbody, thead, tfootが直前に存在せずかつ、唐様粗でない場合*

**終了タグ省略可能**

- HTML
  *直後の文がコメントでない場合*
- HEAD
  *直後が空白文字またはコメントではない場合*
- BODY
  *直後が空白文字ではない場合*
- LI
  *他のLI要素が後についており、親要素に追加コンテンツがない場合*
- DT
  *他のDTまたはDDの要素が後についてる場合*
- DD
  *他のDD要素またはDT要素が後についており、親要素に追加コンテンツがない場合*
- P
  *address, article, aside, blockquote, div, dl, fieldset, footer, form, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, header, hgroup, hr, main, nav, ol, p, pre, section, table, または ulの直後に存在する場合　または　親要素に追加コンテンツがない場合で親要素がaでない場合*
- RB, RT, RTC, RP
  *他のrb, rt, rtc, rp要素が直後に存在する場合　または　親要素に追加コンテンツがない場合*
- OPTIONGROUP
  *他のoptiongroup要素が直後に存在する場合　または　親要素に追加コンテンツがない場合*
- OPTION
  *他のoptiongroup, option要素が直後に存在する場合　または　親要素に追加コンテンツがない場合*
- COLGROUP
  *直後が空白文字またはコメントではない場合*
- THREAD
- tbody or tfootが直後に存在する場合*
- TBODY
  *他のtbody, tfootが直後に存在する場合　または　親要素に追加コンテンツがない場合*
- TFOOT
  *他のtbodyの直後に存在する場合　または　親要素に追加コンテンツがない場合*
- TR
  *別のtrが直後に存在する場合　または　親要素に追加コンテンツがない場合*
- TD, TH
  *別のtd, th要素が直後に存在する場合　または　親要素に追加コンテンツがない場合。*

ただし、(これら全ての場合において、)属性を持つ開始タグは省略できない

**終了タグを必ず省略**

- 空要素として定義されているもの

  - area, base, br, col, embed, hr, img, input, keygen, link, meta, param, source, track, wbr

Answer (score 1):

http://qiita.com/labocho/items/54fd70c73ced35c8ba49

こんなのどうでしょう？
HTML5限定ではありますが、事足りるかと

Comment: リンク先の記事の要約（どの仕様書を見ればよいとしているのか）を書いておくと、より参考になる回答になると思います。リンク先が消える可能性もありますし、後から読む人がリンクをクリックしなくても内容を把握できます。(回答は後から[edit]できます)