# metaタグ末尾に含まれる / (スラッシュ) に特別な意味はありますか？

Tags: html, html5

metaタグの末尾にスラッシュ(`/`)が記載されていますが、何か特別な意味はありますか？
省略しても良い？

[Twitter metaタグ](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/optimize-with-cards/overview/summary)より引用：

```html
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@flickr" />
<meta name="twitter:title" content="Small Island Developing States Photo Submission" />
<meta name="twitter:description" content="View the album on Flickr." />
<meta name="twitter:image" content="https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5510/14338202952_93595258ff_z.jpg" />
```

Comment: 「閉じタグ」とは何でしょうか？ リンク先には特に見当たりませんでした。

Comment: `<...> ～ </...>` ではなく、`<... />` の記法を指している気がします。

Comment: かもしれませんが、正確に何を指しての質問なのかは質問者さんにしかわからないですね。

Comment: XHTML仕様の影響が残っているのでは？ [HTML・XHTML・HTML5におけるMETAタグの書き分け](http://webgaku.hateblo.jp/entry/20120417/1334650334), [Empty Elements Must Also Be Closed - HTML and XHTML](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_xhtml.asp)

Comment: 参考: [HTML要素の終了タグの仕様を確認したい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/5698/32986)

Comment: 「閉じタグ」ではなく「空要素タグ」に関する質問でした

Comment: でしたら質問のタイトルを"metaタグ末尾の/になにか特別な意味はありますか？"みたいな感じに変更すると良いと思います。

Comment: 同じく「閉じタグ」と誤解して検索なさる方がいらっしゃるかもしれないので、検索キーワードとして残しておく程度は良いかなと思っていました。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<名前 属性... >` は「開始タグ」、`</名前>` は「終了タグ」といいます。「閉じタグ」という用語は SGML/XML/HTML の分野にはありません。

`<名前 属性... />` は「空要素タグ」です。XMLでは、要素は開始タグと終了タグの組もしくは空要素タグでなければなりません。HTMLのように開始タグだけの記述はできません。

件のTwitterのページようにHTMLのコード片を紹介するとき、`meta`のようなvoid要素は空要素タグで記述しておくと、それをHTMLのページにコピーしてもXHTMLのページにコピーしても問題なく動くのです。

Comment: HTML5対応だけで良い場合は、「空要素タグ」を「開始タグ」へ変更しても良いですか？

Comment: ブラウザがパーズするのなら変更しても良いですが、Twitterの場合はどうパーズするのか不明なので確かなことはTwitterしか知りません。

Comment: 確かにそうですね。参考になりました

Answer (score 4):

HTML Standard の 12 章 1 節 2 項 1 目によれば、 `void` 要素、 `SVG` 名前空間や `MathML` 名前空間に由来する要素は開始タグに斜線 (`U+002F`) が**存在しても良い**としています<sup>[[1]](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#start-tags)</sup>。

> #### § 12.1.2.1 Start tags<sup>[[1]](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#start-tags)</sup>
>
> Start tags must have the following format:
>
> 6. Then, if the element is one of the void elements, or if the element is a foreign element, then there may be a single U+002F SOLIDUS character (/). This character has no effect on void elements, but on foreign elements it marks the start tag as self-closing.

この文字は `void` 要素に対しては影響を及ぼしませんが、 `SVG`, `MathML` 名前空間に由来する外来要素では自己終了し、内容が空かつ終了タグが存在しないことを示します<sup>[[2]](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#elements-2)</sup>。今回の場合、 `meta` 要素は `void` 要素であるため、開始タグの斜線は存在するかに関わらず、**変化をもたらしません**。

> #### § 12.1.2 Elements<sup>[[2]](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#elements-2)</sup>
>
> There are six different kinds of elements: void elements, the template element, raw text elements, escapable raw text elements, foreign elements, and normal elements.
>
> - **Void elements**
>     `area`, `base`, `br`, `col`, `embed`, `hr`, `img`, `input`, `link`, **`meta`**, `param`, `source`, `track`, `wbr`
> - **Foreign elements**
>     Elements from the `MathML` namespace and the `SVG` namespace.

---

蛇足ですが、 `void` 要素に対する斜線は歴史的経緯によって残っています。過去の仕様には、上記に引用した文章の後ろに以下のような文章が添えられていました<sup>[[3]](https://github.com/whatwg/html/commit/1e78400c39713194e0d6eeb35aa989cb312c41c7#diff-36cd38f49b9afa08222c0dc9ebfe35ebR22879)</sup>。

> Then, if the element is one of the void elements, then there may be a single U+002F SOLIDUS character. This character has no effect except to appease the markup gods. As this character is therefore just a symbol of faith, atheists should omit it.